# Convert two arrays to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, join

I have the lists of fathers and children:

```
const fathers = [
    'Bob',
    'John',
    'Ken',
    'Steve'
];

const children = [
    [ 'Mike', 'David', 'Emma' ],
    [],
    [ 'Harry' ],
    [ 'Alice', 'Jennifer' ]
];
```

How can I convert them to an object like this:

```
const relation = {
    Bob: [ 'Mike', 'David', 'Emma' ],
    John: [],
    Ken: [ 'Harry' ],
    Steve: [ 'Alice', 'Jennifer' ]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const fathers = ['Bob', 'John', 'Ken', 'Steve'];

const children = [
  ['Mike', 'David', 'Emma'],
  [],
  ['Harry'],
  ['Alice', 'Jennifer']
];

const relation = {};
fathers.forEach((item, index) => {
  relation[item] = children[index];
});
console.log(relation);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can convert them into the object as follows.

```js
const fathers = [
    'Bob',
    'John',
    'Ken',
    'Steve'
];

const children = [
    [ 'Mike', 'David', 'Emma' ],
    [],
    [ 'Harry' ],
    [ 'Alice', 'Jennifer' ]
];

const output = fathers.reduce((acc, curV, curI) => ({ ...acc, [curV]: children[curI] }), {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

2 solutions:

First one is to declare an empty object and run over each parent with a loop.

Second one is to use a reducer

```js
var fathers = [
    'Bob',
    'John',
    'Ken',
    'Steve'
];

var children = [
    [ 'Mike', 'David', 'Emma' ],
    [],
    [ 'Harry' ],
    [ 'Alice', 'Jennifer' ]
];

// option 1
  var relations = {};
  fathers.forEach((father, idx) => relations[father] = children[idx])

  console.log(relations);


// option 2
  var relations2 = fathers.reduce((acc, father, idx) => {
      acc[father] = children[idx];
      return acc;
}, {}
)
  console.log(relations2 );
```

Comment: This will return an array of objects... not a single object